# Certain functions are not available when executed with wp_schedule_event

Tags: uploads, wp-cron

I'm publishing post using an schedule event. The publish function uploads an image using `media_sideload_image` and creates a post.

The issue is when this event triggers, it fails with the error `media_sideload_image` as undefined.

I tried running both naturally and via wp crontrol plugin. Both seems to fail. Not sure what is the order when the cron functions are called.

Can someone please help here ?

```
[08-Jun-2021 19:57:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function media_sideload_image() in
```

Below is a skeleton code of how I'm scheduling the function

```
class Post_Scheduler{

    public static function init(){
        register_activation_hook( PLUGIN_FILE, array( __CLASS__, 'on_activate' ) );
        add_action( 'publish_post_action', array( __CLASS__, 'publish_post_func' ) );
    }

    public static function on_activate(){
        if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'publish_post_action' ) ){
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'publish_post_action' );
        }
    }


    public static function publish_post_func(){
        my_function_to_create_post();
    }

}

Post_Scheduler::init();

function my_function_to_create_post(){
    // Some logic
    wp_insert_post();  // This works. Post gets created.

    media_sideload_image(); // But this fails with undefined
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934364/media-sideload-image-gets-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-wp-get-current

Comment: @vancoder Thanks. Any reason why they are not loaded during cron ?

Comment: I'd imagine WP just loads the bare bones on cron for speed, and leaves it up to the dev to include anything else they might need.